Issue with trying to use "light linking" on a single object but affecting all linked objects
I am doing an 3d ring model, with the animation. And after several attempts of the render I wanted to incorporate light linking feature. I like soft shadow how from 2 sources of the light but, it's appealing to me how the additional third light "lIGHT WITH SOFTBOX009" is adding new highlights to the ring. So to have the ring lighten from 2 sources of the light and crystal with 3, I decided that light linking is the best answer for the need of the situation. Unfortunately, I have encountered an issue, that once I am adding crystal to the light linking panel it works on all the other objects. Guess it's because all the elements of the ring are linked together under the "empty for moving object" with the object animation movement. Because all the objects are linked nevertheless I set light linking only for crystal it affects all other objects. Could you guys suggest me anything how to have light linking effect only the crystal and still maintain to have all the objects linked together under the animation empty.
I am adding 2 screenshots for better clarity.
Thanks in advance


